# VisualBasic 2013 ReadMemory

Tags: vb.net, memory

why I only get "0" back? My Code:

```
Dim GeldAdresse As String = "811768"
Dim offsets(1) As Integer
offsets = {&H28, &H2C}
Dim ergebniss As Integer = Memory.ReadPointerInteger("eurotrucks2", 811768, offsets)
```

The Module "Memory":

```
Public Function ReadPointerInteger(ByVal EXENAME As String, ByVal Pointer As Integer, ByVal ParamArray Offset As Integer()) As Integer
        Dim Value As Integer
        If Process.GetProcessesByName(EXENAME).Length <> 0 Then
            Dim Handle As Integer = Process.GetProcessesByName(EXENAME)(0).Handle
            If Handle <> 0 Then
                For Each I As Integer In Offset
                    ReadMemoryInteger(Handle, Pointer, Pointer)
                    Pointer += I
                Next
                ReadMemoryInteger(Handle, Pointer, Value)
            End If
        End If
        Return Value
    End Function
```

In the Example:

```
'       Me.Text = ReadPointerInteger("gta_sa", &HB71A38,&H540,&H544).ToString()
```

Must I convert 0x2C in a Integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is broken. I use antoher.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim Value As Integer
    ...
    Return Value
```

You are returning Value but never assing a real value to it. Looks like you need to change your code to:

```
Dim Value As Integer
...
Value = ReadMemoryInteger(...
...
Return Value
```